# executing a reference to field.onchange in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reference, onchange, executequery

I have HTML code which calls a javascript function from a form, using:

```
<form name="f" id="f" ...>
  <input name="myField" onchange="doFunct(f.myField.value,f.yourField);" />
  <input name="yourfield" onchange="doFunct(f.yourField.value,f.anotherField);" />
...
```

In the javascript code:

```
function doFunct(field,dest){
    // do something with field
    dest.value = field;
    // see if the dest has a change field
    if (dest.onchange !== null) {
        //we have an onchange function, so let's do it!
        dest.onchange();
    }
}
```

This works fine in Safari, Opera, and Chrome.  It fails in FireFox with an error:

**Error: dest.onchange is not a function**

Any suggestions on how to execute "dest.onchange()" from javascript in FireFox?

I need this capability to cascade changes to fields in an input form.

Answer (score 0):

To execute events, do not add the 'on' prefix to it, just run `dest.change();`

Comment: Actually, that's not true.  That ALSO gives an error:
Error: dest.change is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It appears from more research, in my O'Reilly JavaScript Pocket Reference, I find there's a paragraph that states:

`null` (*and undefined*)

The JavaScript keyword `null` is a special value that indicates "no value".  If a variable contains `null`, you know that it does not contain a valid value of any type. There is one other special value in JavaScript: the undefined value.  This is the value returned when you use an undeclared or uninitialized variable or when you use a non-existent object property.  **There is no JavaScript keyword for this value.**

After some testing with alert(dest.onchange) I found that Firefox was not complaining about every invocation of `dest.onchange()` but only those which *were* errors (*undefined*).  Apparently (Grrrr!) Firefox didn't get the memo: [*There is no JavaScript keyword for this value.*]

If I change my code to test for `dest.onchange !== undefined` then Firefox is happy, but then Safari, Opera and Chrome FAIL at the test.  If I change the code as below, it works in all four browsers.

```
if ( (dest.onchange !== null)                // test for safari, chrome, opera
     && (dest.onchange !== undefined) ) {    // test for firefox
    //we have an onchange function, so let's do it!
    dest.onchange();
}
```

And I got to spend 8 hours trying to figure out why Firefox doesn't play nice.